# How to change Ganttchart x-axis title color in amchart?

Tags: angular

[AMCHART Gantt-chart demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2yDw.png)

> Help me to change axis-label-colr without using custmo css in AMGANTTCHART
>   My code below

`"categoryAxis":{
    "boldLabels":true,
    "labelColorField":"#cc0000",
    "color":"blue"
  }`

> I tried this but bot worked

Comment: Check attachment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is solvedby `valueScrollbar` option in amchart. Just make "valueScrollbar":{} then put your property.